# libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found

Tags: c++, gcc, version, std, glibc

First of all, know that I'm very new to c++ and Ubuntu.

I have a program that I am trying to compile using GCC (my version is gcc 4.8.4) by using a makefile.
The problem is that the executable file is created under a directory it works, but when its copied to any other (or even forced to be created there on the makefile) it says.

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
```

Also when i check for versions with strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX, i get:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

As far as I've been reading on the internet the problem is GLIBCXX_3.4.20 is only supported by gcc 4.9 and above while I am using 4.8.4, but still, I don't get why it would work in a specific directory and not in others.

```
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4)
```

As I don't have permissions to update gcc, I would like to know what can I do to solve this...
What things should I avoid to use on the code that are requiring GLIBCXX_3.4.20?
Can I force the compiler to use an older version of that lib somehow or include that specific library in the binary file? (I can't understand why it would work in a directory if I don't have the needed lib)

Thanks in advance and sorry if my question is dumb or makes no sense, as I said I'm very new to this all.

Comment: Seems like you have a problem with 32bits and 64bits versions.

Comment: Doubt we can answer this without being able to see the system or at least more information. You say it works only in one directory but don't tell us what that directory is or where it is or what's in it?

Comment: The system is 64bits,
The directory is a generic one where the binarys are automatically generated on my company. There's nothing more on that dir if I do ls command as people use to move the executables.

Comment: I have been trying commenting and uncommenting all parts of the code and I've got to the answer that the function string.find() is the one giving me that trouble. Tryed changing all the find() to strstr and strchar and the problem works on the directory I told, but still problems when running it outside...

Answer (score 2):

> I have been trying commenting and uncommenting all parts of the code and I've got to the answer that the function string.find() is the one giving me that trouble.

Furious activity is no substitute for understanding.

From the symptoms you described, it is clear that you have two separate versions of `libstdc++.so.6`, and that your program binds to one version when run in a specific directory, and to another when run outside of that directory.

Your first task is then to figure out which versions of `libstdc++.so.6` are being used when. You can do that with:

```
cd /path/to/specific/directory
LD_DEBUG=files,libs /path/to/binary ...args...
```

and compare the output to

```
cd /tmp
LD_DEBUG=files,libs /path/to/binary ...args...
```

Once you know the path to a working `libstdc++.so.6`, you'll need to figure out why you are using it only some of the time, and not all the time.

Common causes include having a *relative* path in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (bad), or in the `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` of the binary itself, or one of the libraries it depends on.

You can examine the `RPATH` this way:

```
readelf -d /path/to/binary | egrep 'RPATH|RUNPATH'
```

Your last step should be to get rid of relative paths (wherever they are coming from -- they are *never* a good idea), and arrange for the correct version of `libstdc++.so.6` to be picked up *allways* (usually by supplying `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/desired/directory` at link time).

Once you've done that, your program should work correctly regardless of which directory you invoked it from.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-10.2.0/gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz

tar xvf gcc-10.2.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-10.2.0
mkdir -p /mnt/distvol/opt/gcc/10.2.0
./configure --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/mnt/distvol/opt/gcc/10.2.0
make -j 2
make install
ln -s /mnt/distvol/opt/gcc/10.2.0/bin/* /usr/bin/ -f
mv /usr/bin/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/bin/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.bak
strings $(find /mnt/distvol/opt/gcc/10.2.0/ -name "libstdc++.so.6") | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.
ln -s /mnt/distvol/opt/gcc/10.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/bin/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```